# Excel table with Sorting - Add new row doesnt automatically resort

Tags: excel

I currently have a table which has sorting A-Z activated.  When I add a new row to the end of the table I would like the table to resort itself.  The sort icon still displays as working so I would've thought that it should've sorted itself.

Is there an option somewhere which I can turn on to automatically keep data sorted?  Or any other solution to this?

The obvious solution is just to re-sort the table.  However, the tables I am creating are being used in drop down lists and I'm creating this Workbook for a group of users that aren't that Excel savvy so am looking for the easiest way for them to maintain these lists.

Example below:  Added the new name "Greg" and it hasn't resorted.

[image]

Comment: Are you open to solutions involving macros and VBA?

Comment: As a last resort yes..i.e. if there is no other solution

Comment: @pnuts I tried the pivot table but when I add a new name to the original list the pivot table doesnt update

Comment: Ok...so it would seem I'm no better off :)